# SharePoint 2010 MySites only allow users to edit their own site

Tags: administration, mysites

In my current SharePoint 2010 development environment I have MySites running for all users for their profiles where they can update and add information about themselves as they need.

For some reason if a user (e.g. SPNormalUser) views another user's profile (e.g. SPAdmin) they are able to edit that person's profile.

How do I disable users from being able to edit each others profiles?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions issue, and most likely you have granted full control to all users.  Validate the user permissions for the service app

1. In CA, under Application Management, click the Manage Service Applications link
2. Select the user profile service application
3. Click the Permissions action in the ribbon
4. Ensure that the Domain Users and All Authenticated Users are not listed here

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I have checked these settings and only SPAdmin has administration rights. I've also checked under User Profile Service->Manage User Permissions but changing options there had no effect.